# Relate log concavity of sequence to convexity of 1/generating function

Tags: generating-functions

Let $Y$ be a random variable on the natural numbers, with $p_k = \mathbb{P}(Y = k)$ for $k \geq 0$.

Say that $Y$ is log-concave if $p_k^2 \geq p_{k-1} p_{k+1}$ for $k \geq 1$, and that $Y$ is log-convex if $p_k^2 \leq p_{k-1} p_{k+1}$ for $k \geq 1$.

Define the generating function of $Y$ to be $G(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} p_k x^k$.

I want to show the following: if $Y$ is log-concave, then $1/G(x)$ is convex on $[0,1]$ and if $Y$ is log-convex, then $1/G(x)$ is concave on $[0,1]$. (It is easy to see that if $Y$ is geometric, then $1/G(x)$ is linear.)

It seems like there should be a simple proof, but it has so far eluded me. What are some references on generating functions or log-concavity that I might find helpful?